# how to convert english letters to other languages in android

Tags: android

I want to convert text typed in english to other languages.
For example if "ela" is typed in English it should automatically convert to "ఎలా" in Telugu(in case if Telugu is selected).As mentioned below

ela--->ఎలా

kaisa--->कैसा

I searched for convertor a lot but can find related to translation.

I cant use google translator in this case so please if any convertor that could convert the text to different languages in android.Please help me.

As in this Site:http://www.quillpad.in/editor.html?utm_source=link&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=maximizeEditor#.VTeVEqbzTFY

How can i implement it in android?
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got the proper answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Call this code which language are selected

and creat all `language` in `value` like this in hindi.... `values-hi->String.xml`

```
   hindilanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {              
            setLocale("hi");
        }

    });

    public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

}
```

this method are use in your `activity` which are be use..and call in your `onCreate()` method..

Comment: You want to run time change language.. means when you type the text then it will be converted.. for selecting language

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes, i want the text to change dynamically in edittext after selection of language.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the google translate Api for android, Obviously you must have a google developer account.

See more [Api-Translator](http://developers.google.com/api-cliente-library/java/apis/translate/v2)

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to use your own script or google api to translitaration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).